# Custom QueryBuilder in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have this problem, I would like to create "smart" criteria. Suppose there's a model of 1 Author : n Books.

So, instead of:

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('Books')->createQueryBuilder('b')
    ->join('b.author', 'a')
    ->where('a.dod is null')
    ->where('a.name = :name')
    ->setParameter('name', 'Mozart');
    ;
```

...i'd like to do something like:

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('Books')->createQueryBuilder('b')
    ->whereAuthorIsAlive()
    ->whereAuthorName('Mozart');
```

I am aware of the possibility to creating custom EntityManager but this is not quite it. Custom QueryBuider would be more suitable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could extend the QueryBuilder with your custom methods, but have a little overhead by overwriting the `createQueryBuilder` method of your repository:

1. Extend the default QueryBuilder class:

```
class BookQueryBuilder extends \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder 
{
    public function whereAuthorIsAlive(): self 
    {
        return $this->join($this->getRootAlias() . '.author', '_a')
            ->andWhere('_a.alive = true');
    }
}
```

2. In your Repository, overwrite the `createQueryBuilder` method:

```
class BookRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy = null)
    {
        return (new BookQueryBuilder($this->_em))
            ->select($alias)
            ->from($this->_entityName, $alias, $indexBy);
    }
}
```

3. Use the new method

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('Books')->createQueryBuilder('b')
    ->whereAuthorIsAlive();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. Only I think createQueryBuilder needs to be: `return (new BookQuery($this->_em))->select($alias)->from($this->_entityName, $alias, $indexBy);` (according to \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::createQueryBuilder)

Comment: sadly ocramius wrote: "In theory, QueryBuilder should be final" https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7868#issuecomment-542225533
 "Putting DQL directly into a NOWDOC string is much more readable" https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/a58yt9/phpstorm_doctrine_query_language_support/eblvfmd/

Comment: I'd argue with NOWDOC. Take my example above (whereAuthorIsAlive, which has 1 join and 1 criterion), nowdoc would not be more readable. And I cant see why the desire to make QueryBuilder final? I think my wishes for custom criteria is perfectly legit :)

Answer (score 1):

I used such kind of the same in a repository.

I created methods in the repository class that added QueryBuilder parts to a query.

In example, based on yours :

```
namespace App\Repository;

class BooksRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    private function whereAuthorIsAlive($qb)
    {
        $qb->where('a.dod is null');
        return $qb;
    }

    private function whereAuthorName($qb, $name)
    {
        $qb->where('a.name = :name')
           ->setParameter('name', $name);

        return $qb;
    }

    public function getBooksByAliveAuthorName($name)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
                   ->join('b.author', 'a')

        $qb = $this->whereAuthorIsAlive($qb);
        $qb = $this->whereAuthorName($qb, $name);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

To register this repository with your entity :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BooksRepository")
 */
class Books
{
    // your entity
}
```

And then, in a controller :

```
$books = $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getRepository('App:Books')
              ->getBooksByAliveAuthorName('Mozart');
```

Comment: Problem is that I have more than 2 criterias, I should write combination for all of them then...? Thats why did not want to use Registry, thats why previous answer is better.