# What is the best practice to add custom methods to the querybuilder based upon existing querybuilder methods?

Tags: doctrine, query-builder

in the following code example i use a custom repository method where i have to call it like this `$queryBuilder = $this->addFilterByVisible($queryBuilder);` but i would like to call it like that `$queryBuilder->andWhere(...)->addFilterByVisible()`

is this possible? is this possible without dealing with AST and adding custom dql functions like descibed here https://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/03/29/doctrine2-custom-dql-udfs.html

is the solution to simply extend the querybuilder and overriding the `createQueryBuilder` method?

this is the current "full" example.

```
class PersonRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    protected function addFilterByVisible(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder): QueryBuilder
    {
        $queryBuilder
            ->andWhere('person_group.visible = :group_is_visible')
            ->andWhere('person.visible = :person_is_visible')
            ->setParameter('group_is_visible', true)
            ->setParameter('person_is_visible', true)
        ;

        return $queryBuilder;
    }

    protected function queryAllSorted()
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('person');
        $queryBuilder
            ->innerjoin('person.group', 'person_group')
            ->addSelect('person_group')
        ;
        $queryBuilder = $this->addFilterByVisible($queryBuilder);

        return $queryBuilder;
    }
}
```

for reference: how to create a custom querybuilder
[Custom QueryBuilder in Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307923/custom-querybuilder-in-doctrine)

Comment: Have you tried extending QueryBuilder to PersonQueryBuilder, adding your method to it, then in your PersonRepository, overriding createQueryBuilder() to return your PersonQueryBuilder rather than the default one? Not sure if it'd work, but might be worth a try? It'd only apply to PersonRepository though.

Comment: @gingerCodeNinja thanks for you answer, already done that. i am looking for the "right way" to do it / for the best pratice. it looks like simply extending the querybuilder and adding the methods there is the "right way".

Comment: Sorry, I missed the sentence where you said you already thought about that! :) I'm sure someone else will have a better answer.

On a side note, we're trying to keep our repositories really simple - trying not to extend default EntityRepository where possible, and adding layer above that, "Managers" which use the EntityRepository as a service. So a PersonManager, which has a few getters/finders, wrapping EntityRepository->createQueryBuilder with logic. A Manager for each specific type of query, so more in keeping with S.O.L.I.D and more easily unit testable.